# copying preferences and add-ons from older version to a new one

Tags: customization

trying to copy preferences and more importantly, add-ons from an older version of Blender (2.75 to 2.79b) The tread that has been closed that claims to work does not work for me. Need help please. Working on MacBook Pro running High Sierra. What's with the editing to make humans sound like robots? What happened to the other Blender forum? I like that one much better.

Comment: Thanks god I found it. So long!!! I'll search for answers hear when I 'm desperate but I won't actively participate. Kinda blows....

Comment: Why did you edit out link to the related question? It helps getting the context more than "thread that claims to work". If something isn't working explain why please by posting details what you did and what did you expect to happen. This is not a forum, forum is at https://blenderartists.org/

Comment: This is not a forum. Please take the [tour] to understand how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

Copying the preferences file does not copy the script files for the addons. Addons can live in a few places: the folder where blender is installed (you might need to use the [show package contents](https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/how-to-inspect-an-os-x-package-file-pkg-without-installing) for the blender.app on a mac blender.app/Contents/Resources//scripts) or on the directories listed in this link: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html#macos

Just copy the addon you nedd to the current version you need and enable it in the system preferences.